# Which procedure takes the minimum time to solve modulus functions?

Tags: functions, absolute-value

1. -|2x-3|+|5-x|+|x-10|=|3-x|
2. |2x-3|-|5-x|-|x-10|-|3-x|=28
3. -|2x-3|+|5-x|+|x-10|≥|3-x|

How can we solve these problems?

The method I know is to plug in the critical values to see which modulus becomes positive and which one becomes negative. Then find out the values of x for which the above conditions become true.

For example, if I am asked to solve the first problem, I will do the following steps.

Step-1: Find out the critical values.

For 2x-3, critical value is 3/2.

For 5-x, critical value is 5.

For x-10, critical value is 10.

For 3-x, critical value is 3.

Step-2: When x is less than 3/2, we can write the first equation in the following form:

(2x-3)-(x-5)-(x-10)=-(x-3)

or, 2x-3-x+5-x+10=-x+3

or, x=-9

When 1.5≤x<3,

-(2x-3)-(x-5)-(x-10)=-(x-3)

or, -2x+3-x+5-x+10=-x+3

or, -4x+18=-x+3

or, -3x=-15

or, x=5

x=5 isn't acceptable because we assumed x<3.

We can repeat the step-2 for 3≤x<5, 5≤x<10 and x≥10.

This procedure is very long and a time consumable process.

Is there other way that requires less time and less effort to solve the above problems?

Once I have seen a person to use a number line to solve this sort of problem. However, his explanation works when there is a poisitive sign between two modulus functions, and a value at the right hand side of the equation.

For example, we can consider the following equation.

4. |x-5|+|x-2|=9

We can imagine a number line where two people are standing at two points. One person is 2 units away from zero (center point), and other person is 5 units away from zero. Both persons are standing at the right hand side of center point. They want to meet on such a point for which together they will have to travel total 9 units.

So if the person who is two units away from center point moves right, they can meet on a point which is 8 units away from center point. Hence total distance travelled by them will be now 9 units. So, now we have x=8.

If we repeat this same procedure for the left hand side, we will find x=-1 which is just one unit away from zero (center point). And to reach that point, both of them will have to travel total 9 units.

However, this procedure doesn't work for the equations like 1,2 and 3.

Now I am here to ask the experts of this site to let me know some other ways which can help solve the above equations within shortest possible time.

Comment: For the question of what procedure to follow when attacking similar problems, I think that your analysis nailed it.  That is, you consider that each expression $|f(x)|$, where $f$ is a linear function, will represent $+f(x)$ in one interval, and $-f(x)$ in another interval.  Also, as you already indicated, when faced with an equation that involves (for example) $|x-5| + |x-2|$, you have only $(3)$ intervals rather than (4) intervals: $x < 2, 2 \leq x < 5,$ and $5 \leq x$.  ...see next comment

Comment: Things get more complicated when $|f(x)|$ involves a non-linear function $f$, because you have more trouble determining exactly when $f(x)$ is negative.  Also, although very experienced mathematicians will sometimes see an elegant alternative in one specific problem, that doesn't imply that there will always be an elegant alternative.  Further, even if there is an elegant alternative, someone less experienced in Math could easily burn an hour looking, and not find the elegance.  Why do that, when the (tedious, industrial strength) *standard* approach will solve the problem in less than 30 min?

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite your first equation as
$$|x-5|+|x-10|=|x-3| + |2x-3| $$
For $x\ge 10,$ get $2x-15=3x-6,$ impossible,

For $5\le x \le 10,$ lhs $=5,$ but $|2x-3|$ is much bigger.

For $3\le x\le 5,\ \  15-2x=3x-6,$ which gives the solution
$$x=4.2$$